# What ion engine is used by Hayabusa2?

Tags: propulsion, ion-thruster, jaxa

Hayabusa2 is on its final approach to asteroid 162173 Ryugu, expected to arrive in July 2018.

Like its predecessor, Hayabusa2 uses an ion thruster for deep-space propulsion, but I can't find any information on the exact engine.

**What is the name of the engine on board Hayabusa2 and what performance (specific impulse) can it achieve?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Searching for "hayabusa 2 thruster specifications" leads me to a paper titled [Development and Testing of the Hayabusa2 Ion Engine System](http://erps.spacegrant.org/uploads/images/2015Presentations/IEPC-2015-333_ISTS-2015-b-333.pdf). The thruster is called µ10, four of them are used in a single gimbaling mount, and the specific impulse ranges from 2740 s to 2890 s depending on power level. Thrust is 6.3-9.0 mN.

Comment: Also just found it Googling for "Hayabusa2 ion thruster" ;-) See section *I. Microwave Discharge Ion Engine System*

Comment: Not quite sure how I missed that! That paper's a real treasure trove - impressive how they improved the thrust by some 20% for such a small power increase from Hayabusa 1.

Comment: A far cry below the 129kW of the 1,299cc Hayabusa engine. =)

Answer (score 3):

It's a custom engine designed for the mission, [based on the "IES" engine from Haybusa1](http://www.jspf.or.jp/jspf_annual2015/JSPF32/pdf/S2-6.pdf).  There's a [paper on the design and construction](http://www.jspf.or.jp/jspf_annual2015/JSPF32/pdf/S2-6.pdf) that claims a specific impulse of 2740 – 2890 (s), about the same as Hayabusa1.

Comment: Russell Borogove's answer points to a more recent paper with more info.